# Resetting Ghost default fonts

Tags: css, ghost

I was messing around in the Ghost admin panel under Code Injection settings and succeeded in changing the text color of my HTML `<code>` blocks to from red to black.

Now that I've made the change, I can't figure out how to undo it.

Adding a `<style>` block doesn't seem to change anything, nor does a dynamic script seem to help.

Edit: I verified that it's not a caching issue, nor is it limited to a specific browser.

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Himesh, I'm not sure you're familiar with the Ghost blogging engine. This isn't a self-hosted account, so there's no visible code for me to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the left-hand side of the Ghost admin screen is a tab titled "Code Injection". In this section, Ghost offers users the ability to inject valid HTML/CSS/JS on the top or bottom of each post.

I tried a number of possible solutions in there, but out of desperation, went back and tried using a `<style>` block once more. I was able to change the color by entering this value in the header, saving changes, then deleting and saving again:

```
<style>
    code {
        color: black;
    }
</style>
```

It's possible that I entered my formatting fixes into the `<footer>` box or mistyped a character, but I'd be curious to know which.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue as Michael mentioned above. Code injection presumably by-passes that (since it's inline css)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your browser cache (or holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> at the same time in your browser) and then try again. Ghost makes heavy use of caching.